# How to change the Top Bar tab titles

Tags: 2013, master-page, sharepoint-addin, page-layout, css

I have a requirement to change the Top bar titles for my team site and community site. For example I need to change the “Page” to be “Page options”.so from where I can change these titles.?
Second question I have three different types of lists inside my team site, and each list have a Page tab, so can I change the title per list, or I only can do this for the whole site. As inside the document management library  I want the Page to be “Document library options”, and for the announcement list I want it to be “Announcement Options “instead of being “Page” for both.

[image]

**EDIT**
I have created the following script insde my Style library folder:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){$("#Ribbon\\.WebPartPage-title span").first().html('PAGE OPTIONS');
$('.ms-cui-tts').click(function() {
    $('#Ribbon\\.WebPartPage-title span').first().html('PAGE OPTIONS');
 });
$('#Ribbon\\.WebPartPage-title a').click(function() {
        $('#Ribbon\\.WebPartPage-title span').first().html('PAGE OPTIONS');});
 });
```

then i reference the script inside my master page as follow , before the  tag :-

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="/sites/Intranet/Style Library/JS/changetitles.js" ></script>

</head>
```

But it did not chnage the title ?

Comment: Are you referencing a js that is in other site collection? Maybe there is the problem /sites/Intranet/Style Library/JS/changetitles.js. If you are in the same site collection just use src="/Style Library/JS/changetitles.js"

Comment: No it is on the same site collection, anyway i chnage it to "/Style Library/JS/changetitles.js" but stil the page title did not change, baring in mind that i have other scripts on the same Js folder and i am calling them on the same way and they are working well? not sure what is going on ?

Comment: Could you open Firebug with firefox and put a breakpoint on the .js in the next line after $(document).ready(function() ant check if it stops there?

Comment: Did you resolve your issue with my solution? If not, post the solution please.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by adding this code into your .js file

```
$("#Ribbon\\.WebPartPage-title span").html('PAGE OPTIONS');
```

I don't understand the second question. For document libraries the option is "`LIBRARY`" not "`PAGE`". And for custom lists the option tab is `LIST`. Can you update your post with a screen capture of those options in your custom lists?

**UPDATED**

Try this. It worked for me. This is the best approach I can give you right now

```
$(document).ready(function(){$("#Ribbon\\.WebPartPage-title span").first().html('PAGE OPTIONS');
$('.ms-cui-tts').click(function() {
    $('#Ribbon\\.WebPartPage-title span').first().html('PAGE OPTIONS');
 });
$('#Ribbon\\.WebPartPage-title a').click(function() {
        $('#Ribbon\\.WebPartPage-title span').first().html('PAGE OPTIONS');});
 });
```

[image]

I got working putting that code in my js before ending `</head>`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Style Library/js/navigation.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, so i need to create a custom JS file inside my style library ? and then write all the renaming ?

Comment: Yes it would be an approach. Or if you already have custom .js files you could put your code there with <!-- Tab Personalization Section -->

Comment: i have added the following Script <script type= "application/javascript">
$("#Ribbon\\.WebPartPage-title span").html('PAGE OPTIONS');
</script>
at the end of my master page ,, but it did not change the Page to "Page Options" ? any advice please

Comment: It doesn't work because surely you don't have reference JQuery .js in the master page. If you do, remove the double \\

Comment: I will addthe Jquery reference. but i am not sure how in this way i can change the title for the Item tab, library tab ,etc..

Comment: Adding this reference PAGE literal has been changed by PAGE OPTIONS? I will tell you how to changue the others

Comment: ok i reference Jquery , then i added $("#Ribbon.WebPartPage-title span").html('PAGE OPTIONS'); at the end of the seatle.master page,, but nothing have been changed ?

Comment: Have you tested with both "#Ribbon.WebPartPage.title span" and "#Ribbon\\.WebPartPage.title span" once the JQuery reference is added?

Comment: i have added the following to the end of the seatle.master before closing the body tag. 
$("#Ribbon\\.WebPartPage-title span").html('PAGE OPTIONS');
$("#Ribbon.WebPartPage-title span").html('PAGE OPTIONS');

</body>
but this did not change the title to "Page Options"

Comment: Read the updated answer please

Comment: thanks for the update i added these just before the end of the body tag inside my seatle.master,, but they did not chnage the page tab title..

Comment: can you check my Edit